# Is there a vectorized way to find maxes within labeled areas in NumPy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D array representing tree heights, where `0` is the ground. I have another array that's always the same size showing segmented and labeled trees, where a `0` label means ground, and a positive integer value represents a unique tree. Here are some slices of the data:

```
heights = array([[37.5 , 41.82, 42.18, 42.18, 42.18, 39.23, 40.68, 40.71, 40.71,
        40.19, 35.03, 41.41, 41.41, 41.41, 40.77, 32.23, 32.23, 32.23,
        31.45, 25.6 , 25.63, 30.12, 30.78, 30.78, 30.92],
       [37.5 , 37.5 , 41.82, 42.18, 41.78, 41.78, 40.68, 40.68, 40.68,
        40.19, 41.04, 41.41, 41.41, 41.41, 41.03, 32.23, 32.23, 32.23,
        31.25, 25.6 , 25.6 , 30.12, 30.12, 21.08, 30.88],
       [37.5 , 37.5 , 34.61, 41.78, 41.78, 25.6 , 39.14, 40.68, 38.79,
        38.79, 41.04, 41.04, 41.8 , 41.8 , 41.8 , 24.66, 24.66, 31.25,
        25.63, 26.24, 26.2 , 25.2 , 24.93, 21.03, 21.03],
       [34.53, 34.61, 34.61, 35.23, 35.23, 25.32, 25.32, 33.17, 33.17,
        38.86, 39.4 , 40.31, 41.8 , 41.8 , 41.8 , 41.17, 25.37, 26.77,
        27.32, 27.39, 27.39, 26.96, 25.2 , 28.68, 28.68],
       [34.53, 34.52, 36.5 , 36.58, 36.67, 36.67, 25.15, 33.17, 38.65,
        38.86, 39.4 , 39.53, 40.78, 41.17, 41.17,  0.  , 26.77, 27.09,
        27.39, 27.6 , 27.6 , 28.  , 28.16, 28.68, 28.68],
       [32.22, 36.45, 37.1 , 37.28, 37.28, 38.07, 30.98, 31.12, 38.65,
        38.65, 39.12, 39.4 , 40.78, 40.78,  0.  ,  0.  , 27.41, 27.72,
        27.72, 28.49, 28.49, 28.16, 28.34, 28.87, 28.68],
       [36.45, 37.1 , 37.1 , 37.28, 38.23, 38.23, 38.23, 33.61, 32.31,
        38.65, 38.65, 38.62, 39.01, 33.75, 34.65, 34.65, 27.41, 27.72,
        27.72, 28.49, 28.49, 28.49, 28.87, 30.31, 30.31],
       [35.71, 36.45, 37.1 , 30.96, 38.23, 38.23, 38.23, 33.61, 33.28,
        33.42, 33.5 , 33.5 , 33.51, 34.07, 34.65, 34.65, 27.36, 27.83,
        27.83, 28.49, 28.49, 28.43, 28.87, 31.82, 31.68],
       [14.44,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , 21.41, 32.98, 33.61, 33.61, 34.27,
        34.8 , 34.8 , 33.5 , 33.4 , 34.07, 34.65, 34.65,  0.  , 27.83,
        27.83, 28.7 , 29.18, 29.18, 31.82, 31.82, 31.98],
       [13.46,  0.  ,  0.  , 21.41, 21.73, 31.36, 33.33, 33.33, 34.89,
        34.99, 34.99, 32.72, 33.4 , 33.8 , 33.8 ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
        28.7 , 28.7 , 29.64, 29.64, 31.82, 31.82, 35.82],
       [13.46,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , 21.73, 31.36, 31.46, 35.81, 36.33,
        36.33, 36.33, 32.72, 33.37, 33.71, 33.71,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
        28.7 , 29.64, 29.64, 29.77, 29.77, 29.77, 35.95],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , 24.07, 31.57, 35.9 , 36.33,
        36.33, 36.33, 21.97, 32.72, 33.37, 33.37,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
        28.36, 29.04, 29.64, 29.77, 29.77, 29.77, 35.95],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , 22.09, 24.07, 23.92, 31.57, 35.9 ,
        36.33,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
        28.38, 29.53, 28.96, 28.96, 28.69, 29.19, 35.49],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  , 22.09, 22.09, 22.09,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
        29.53, 29.53, 29.82, 28.96, 28.73, 29.19, 29.19],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
        29.53, 30.12, 30.12, 29.82, 28.73,  0.  , 28.89],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  , 30.12, 30.12, 30.12, 28.94,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  , 30.12, 30.12, 29.82,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  , 28.65, 28.65,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,
         0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ]], dtype=float32)
```

```
labeled_trees = array([[33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37,
        37, 37, 37, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39],
       [33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37,
        37, 37, 37, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39],
       [33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37,
        37, 37, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39],
       [33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37,
        37, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39],
       [33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37,  0,
        39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39],
       [33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37,  0,  0,
        39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39],
       [33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37,
        37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39],
       [33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37,
        37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39],
       [33,  0,  0,  0, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 37, 37, 37, 37,
         0, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39],
       [33,  0,  0, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 37, 37, 37,  0,
         0,  0, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39],
       [33,  0,  0,  0, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 37, 37, 37,  0,
         0,  0, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 37, 37, 37,  0,
         0,  0, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0,  0, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0, 33, 33, 33,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0,  0, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0,  0, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39,  0, 39],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0,  0,  0, 39, 39, 39, 39,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0,  0,  0, 39, 39, 39,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0,  0,  0, 39, 39,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=int32)
```

I'd like to find the max height within each labeled region. I have done this successfully with a for loop, but it's slow.

```
max_heights = {}
for label in list(np.unique(labeled_trees))[1:]:
    tree_height = np.amax(heights[labeled_trees == label])
    max_heights[str(label)] = tree_height

# max_heights = {'33': 42.18, '37': 41.8, '39': 35.95}
```

Is there a faster/vectorized/more efficient way of finding the max values within labeled regions of a numpy array? The ideal output would be a boolean array where the location of each max is `True`.

[EDIT]

The [`maximum_position`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.maximum_position.html#scipy.ndimage.maximum_position) function from `scipy.ndimage` is promising, but it looks like the it only returns the first location where the pixel equals the local max. I need every location within a labeled region that equals its max.

Comment: Just wondering if you would like to use the Pandas way?

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew I'm not opposed to that, but knowing a way to do it with NumPy is still worthwhile to me

Comment: Just wondering why are using AMAX instead of MAX ?

Comment: Have you profiled this? Unless you have a very large number of trees/labels, the loop on labels might not be the slow part

Comment: @anon01 I don't know what you mean by profiled. I did take a subset of my actual array, which is `(2500, 2500)` in size with potentially 10,000+ trees.

Comment: @Abhishek no reason on `amax`, as far as I understand it's interchangeable with `max`.

Comment: here's a reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html. Its often a good idea to see whats actually slow rather than guessing to avoid wasted effort

Comment: @anon01 Thanks for the reference and advice, good to know.

Comment: Scipy has some functions to deal with labelled data, [link to the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html#measurements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a much simpler use of `np.maximum.reduceat`:

```
idx = labeled_trees.argsort(None)
sorted_labeled_trees = labeled_trees.ravel()[idx]
sorted_heights = heights.ravel()[idx]
bins = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(sorted_labeled_trees) != 0) + 1
max_heights = np.maximum.reduceat(sorted_heights, bins)
max_trees = sorted_labeled_trees[bins]
```

If you insist on a dictionary, you can make one with `zip`:

```
result = dict(zip(max_trees, max_heights))
```

If you want a mask of the positions where the maxima occur and the number of trees is relatively small, you can compute the mask more-or-less directly using broadcasting:

```
peak_mask = ((max_trees == labeled_trees[..., None]) & (max_height == heights[..., None])).any(-1)
```

If the number of trees is not small, you will be better off using a loop over the labels:

```
peak_mask = np.zeros(labeled_trees.shape, bool)
for t, h in zip(max_trees, max_height):
    peak_mask |= (labeled_trees == t) & (heights == h)
```

Comment: Actually, I don't insist on a dictionary, it's just a data structure I'm comfortable with :) Ideally, I need a boolean array of every location within a labeled region that equals its max, even if that max value appears more than once within its labeled region.

Comment: @jesnes. I added the check you requested

Comment: This is slick, I really like your binning trick, it's sneaky-good. I'm testing this against some of the other answers on here, because ultimately there will be places where the number of trees could be 10,000+. I tested this on a real `(2500, 2500)` tile with ~1000 trees and it took about 30 seconds. Not sure at what point it's a computer optimization issue vs a volume of data issue.

Comment: @jesnes 30 sec sounds excessive for 6.25M points. At the same time, the final step will be prohibitive, since you're creating a 6.25B point temporary mask.

Comment: @jesnes. I added an option you can try to use for mask with 1000 trees

Comment: @jesnes. I take it the last option sped things up a bit?

Comment: `5.54 s +/- 134 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: @jesnes. That's not great, but definitely better than 30sec :)

Comment: Agreed! Thanks much, you helped me learn more than I expected, particularly when it comes to flattening arrays.

Comment: @jesnes. Always ravel, never flatten :) Flattening makes a copy, raveling (usually) makes a view.

Answer (score 2):

This returns the ideal output you need, but it is not fast enough. On my machine, it needs about 60 µs:

```
def max_mask(labeled_trees, heights):
    cmp = labeled_trees.reshape(1, -1) != np.unique(labeled_trees)[1:, None]
    indices = np.ma.masked_array(np.broadcast_to(heights.ravel(), cmp.shape), cmp).argmax(-1)
    ret = np.zeros(heights.size, bool)
    ret[indices] = True
    return ret.reshape(heights.shape)
```

Some explanations:

1. The first step is to use broadcast to return the comparison result of each value of `np.unique(labeled_trees)[1:]` with `labeled_trees.ravel()`, which will be a 2d array with the shape of `(np.unique(labeled_trees)[1:].size, labeled_trees.size)`. The equivalent code is given below:

```
cmp = np.array([labeled_tree.ravel() != elem for elem in np.unique(labeled_tree)[1:]])
```

2. The second step is to flatten the `heights` and broadcast it as the shape of `cmp` as the value of `np.ma.masked_array`, `cmp` as the mask, and then find `argmax` for the mask array, which will find out the position of the maximum value of the valid part for each sub array. The equivalent code is given below:

```
indices = np.array([np.ma.masked_array(heights, mask).argmax() for mask in cmp])
```

3. The remaining steps are very simple. We have already got the position of the maximum value of each unique value range of `heights`. Just create a bool array of the same size and set the corresponding position to True, finally reshape and return.

Test:

```
>>> print(max_mask(labeled_trees, heights).astype(int))
[[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
>>> heights[max_mask(labeled_trees, heights)]
array([42.18, 41.8 , 35.95])
```

**Better performance version:** Here I refer to the impletementation of `masked_array.argmax` to get a faster method. On my machine, it only needs about 22 μs:

```
def max_mask(labeled_trees, heights):
    cmp = labeled_trees.reshape(1, -1) != np.unique(labeled_trees)[1:, None]
    indices = np.where(cmp, -np.inf, heights.ravel()).argmax(-1)
    ret = np.zeros(heights.size, bool)
    ret[indices] = True
    return ret.reshape(heights.shape)
```

In order to avoid the possible copy caused by `labeled_trees.reshape`, it can be changed to the following form:

```
def max_mask(labeled_trees, heights):
    cmp = labeled_trees[None] != np.unique(labeled_trees)[1:, None, None]
    indices = np.where(cmp, -np.inf, heights).reshape(-1, heights.size).argmax(-1)
    ret = np.zeros(heights.size, bool)
    ret[indices] = True
    return ret.reshape(heights.shape)
```

**More consistent with ideal output version:** I noticed that you asked "every location within a labeled region that equals its max", and I updated the answer again, it needs about 34 μs to run on my machine:

```
def max_mask(labeled_trees, heights):
    cmp = labeled_trees[None] != np.unique(labeled_trees)[1:, None, None]
    masked = np.where(cmp, -np.inf, heights).reshape(-1, heights.size)
    return (masked.max(-1, keepdims=True) == masked).any(0).reshape(heights.shape)
```

Test:

```
>>> print(max_mask(labeled_trees, heights).astype(int))
[[0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
>>> heights[max_mask(labeled_trees, heights)]
array([42.18, 42.18, 42.18, 42.18, 41.8 , 41.8 , 41.8 , 41.8 , 41.8 ,
       41.8 , 35.95, 35.95])
```

**Supplement:** the above version has been vectorized as much as possible, but it requires a large amount of memory (especially when `np.unique(labeled_trees)` is very large). I tested it with random numbers and found that its speed will be seriously slowed down due to memory problems. Therefore, a solution using loops is provided here. It requires very little memory:

```
def max_mask_loop(labeled_trees, heights):
    ret = np.zeros(heights.shape, bool)
    for val in np.unique(labeled_trees)[1:]:
        masked = np.where(labeled_trees != val, -np.inf, heights)
        ret |= masked.max() == masked
    return ret
```

Comparison:

```
>>> heights = np.random.rand(2500, 2500)
>>> labeled_trees = np.random.randint(0, 300, heights.shape)
>>> timeit(lambda: max_mask(labeled_trees, heights), number=1)
37.30420290003531
>>> timeit(lambda: max_mask_loop(labeled_trees, heights), number=1)
9.9376986999996
```

Comment: Freakin' sweet! Could you please add comments to the function? I think I understand what's going on in each line, but not entirely.

Comment: @jesnes I added the explanation, and you can learn more about the role of [masked_array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.generic.html), where it plays a key role.

Comment: @jesnes I have updated the method with better performance. Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Check Below pure numpy implementation using **[reduceat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html)**

```
## Step 1 Flatten Array
height_1d = heights[labeled_trees>0].reshape(1,-1)[0]
labeled_trees_1d = labeled_trees[labeled_trees>0].reshape(1,-1)[0]

## Step 2 : Sort arrays while maintaining there relationship
srt_indicies = labeled_trees_1d.argsort()
sorted_heights = height_1d[srt_indicies]
sorted_labeled_trees = labeled_trees_1d[srt_indicies]

## Extract indices where maximum need to be found
_, idx = np.unique(sorted_labeled_trees, return_index=True)

## Use maximum.reduce to find array and dict comprehension for final output
{str(key):value for  key, value  in zip(list(sorted_labeled_trees[idx]) ,list(np.maximum.reduceat(sorted_heights, idx))) if key > 0}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: How could I use this method to get my ideal output? I put these maxes in a dict because I'm comfortable with those data structures, but I'd like to have a boolean array where the location of each max is `True`.

Comment: Yeah my bad, missed the part "The ideal output would be a boolean array where the location of each max" was just focusing on output

Comment: Unique already uses a sort. Use `return_inverse=True` to take advantage of that.